# Multiple OutputCache in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache

Can we have multiple `OutputCache` defined for an action? For ex. say I want to store `OutputCache` copy one in `Server` and another one in `Client`. I know that this we can do with `Location=OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient` but say I want to specify different `Duration` for `Client` and `Server`, having a bigger `Duration` for `Server` and smaller `Duration` for `Client`? So with this requirement can I have it as below?

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam = "pID", NoStore = true)] //Server Cache for 1 hour
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "pID", NoStore = true)] //Client Cache for 10 minutes
public ActionResult GetDetails(string pID)
{
    //some code
    return View(model);
}
```

Will this be valid to have or `MVC` takes latest `OutputCache` into consideration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source of [OutputCacheAttribute](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs) you will notice that the attribute is defined with `AllowMultiple` property set to false:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class OutputCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
```

So it won't work

Comment: Can we override this?

Comment: Also, any alternative for my requirement or thought?

Comment: You can not override this behavior by simply extending default  OutputCacheAttribute. This thread could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823057/how-to-set-different-cache-expire-times-for-client-and-server-caches